# Sorting a singly linked list with multiple elements in C

Tags: c, sorting

I've been working on this code as a practice for one of the assignments that involves multiple arrays in C.

I've come this far, but I need a little help with the sorting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Cricket
{
    char player_name[15];
    int matches;
    int runs;
    struct Cricket *next;
} cricket;

// cricket temporary;

cricket *creating_the_list(int n);
void displaying_the_list(cricket *head);
void _bubble_sort(cricket *head);
float average(int k, int r);

int main(void)
{
    cricket *HEAD = NULL;
    int n;
    int x;

    do
    {
        printf("How many players do you require in the team: ");
        x = scanf(" %d", &n);
        getchar();
    } while (x != 1);

    HEAD = creating_the_list(n);
    _bubble_sort(HEAD);
    displaying_the_list(HEAD);
}

cricket *creating_the_list(int n)
{
    cricket *head = NULL;
    cricket *temp = NULL;
    cricket *p = NULL;
    int x, y;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        temp = (cricket *)malloc(sizeof(cricket));

        printf("%d.Please enter your name: ", i + 1);
        scanf(" %s", (temp->player_name));

        do
        {
            printf("%d.Please enter the number of matches you've played: ", i + 1);
            x = scanf(" %d", &(temp->matches));
            getchar();
        } while (x != 1);

        do
        {
            printf("%d.Please enter the runs you've scored: ", i + 1);
            y = scanf(" %d", &(temp->runs));
            getchar();
        } while (y != 1);

        temp->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            p = head;
            while (p->next != NULL)
            {
                p = p->next;
            }
            p->next = temp;
        }
    }
    return head;
}

void displaying_the_list(cricket *head)
{
    cricket *display = head;
    printf("\nName\t\tMatches\t\tRuns\tAverage\n");
    while (display != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%.2f\n", display->player_name, display->matches, display->runs, average(display->runs, display->matches));
        display = display->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

float average(int k, int r)
{
    float average = (float)k / r;
    return average;
}

void _bubble_sort(cricket *head)
{
    cricket *temp1, *temp2;
    int swap;

    for (temp1 = head; temp1 != NULL; temp1 = temp1->next)
    {
        for (temp2 = head; temp2->next != NULL; temp2 = temp2->next)
        {
            if (temp1->runs > temp2->runs)
            {
                swap = temp1->runs;
                temp1->runs = temp2->runs;
                temp2->runs = swap;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code sorts them by runs, but ends up mixing the values. Even though the desired output would be to sort them by the number of runs they've scored and still keep their names/matches intact.

I'd be grateful, if someone could point out the mistake or help me solve it. Cheers.

Comment: Don't swap the values contained in the nodes, but swap the nodes directly

Comment: You should avoid identifiers which start with a `_`, like `_bubble_sort`.

Comment: @Cid Please turn that into an explained answer. (Or invite other users to do that for you.)

Comment: @Yunnosch I'd rather find a duplicate, I think I already saw this kind of question on SO

Comment: This one seems nice :)

Comment: @Yunnosch Hi, first of all, this was a very rough version of the code so I didn't pay much attention to the naming of functions/variables. Secondly, I didn't really know how to post a question/your code on here, so I'll look it up and edit the "mess of a shown code". Apologies! :)